# SPRING-DM SUPPORTED IN jboss-fuse-6.2 ONWARDS?

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb, blueprint-osgi, spring-dm

We are using jboss fuse `6.1.0.redhat-379` and are planning to upgrade to `6.2.1.redhat-621166`. But so far we have used `spring-dm` for all of the bundles.
My question to the jboss fuse esb users is whether from 6.2 onwards, use of blueprint is mandatory or `spring-dm` will also be supported for some more  time.
Though I fully understand that blueprint is the standard and recommendation for osgi, but if spring-dm will not be supported in 6.2, I may have to  delay the upgrade for sometime.
All good ideas/suggestions are welcome.

Appreciate  any  quick  help.

Answer (score 1):

`Spring-DM is now deprecated` states the headline of the following [document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/html/Migration_Guide/ESBMigrationIntro-SpringDM.html), also the [6.3 Migration guide](https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Migration_Guide-en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Migration_Guide-en-US.pdf) states that it is, however you are still able to use it then.

In general the shift is towards containers, so I'd keep an eye on technologies like `spring-boot` or `docker` and `kubernetes`, because bets are, the upcoming major version (7.0) will be relying heavily on these.